# Links to control Flash Navigation

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am trying to create a link on a page that mimicks the existing flash navigation and get it to work as expected, meaning that when you click the link, the site navigation reflects the change.
The problem I'm having is that I don't understand the hierarchy since I'm working from outside the navigation system itself.

I can get the animation to change on rollOver and rollOut but when I click the link, the page changes from page1 to page2 but the navigation is still showing page1.

```
//This is the code in the existing navigation

    onClipEvent (load) {
        num=2;
        _parent.t1.gotoAndStop(num);
    }
    on (rollOver) {
        if (_root.link<>num) {
            _parent.gotoAndPlay("s1");
        }
    }
    on (releaseOutside, rollOut) {
        if (_root.link<>num) {
            _parent.gotoAndPlay("s2");
        }
    }
    on (release) {
        if (_root.link<>num and _root.animation ==1) {
            _root.animation =0;
            _root.link_prev = _root.link;
            _parent._parent["item"+_root.link].gotoAndPlay("s2");
            _root.link = num;
            _root.play ();
        }
    }

//This is the code for my link outside the navigation.  
//I've adjusted the rollOver and rollOut line to point to 
//the specific link but the release remains a mystery to me. 
//I'm not sure how to adjust it.

    onClipEvent (load) {
        num=2;
        _parent.t1.gotoAndStop(num);
    }
    on (rollOver) {
        _root.menu.item2.gotoAndPlay("s1");
    }
    on (rollOut) {
        _root.menu.item2.gotoAndPlay("s2");
    }
    on (release) {
        if (_root.link<>num and _root.animation ==1) {
            _root.animation =0;
            _root.link_prev = _root.link;
            _parent._parent["item"+_root.link].gotoAndPlay("s2");
            _root.link = num;
            _root.play();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

```
    onClipEvent (load) {
    num=2;
   //Change following line from _parent.t1. to _root.menu.t1
    _root.menu.t1.gotoAndStop(num);
}
on (rollOver) {
    if (_root.link<>num) {
        _parent.gotoAndPlay("s1");
    }
}
on (releaseOutside, rollOut) {
    if (_root.link<>num) {
        _parent.gotoAndPlay("s2");
    }
}
on (release) {
    if (_root.link<>num and _root.animation ==1) {
        _root.animation =0;
        _root.link_prev = _root.link;
        //change following line from _parent._parent to _root.menu
        _root.menu["item"+_root.link].gotoAndPlay("s2");
        _root.link = num;
        _root.play ();
        //Add this line also
        _root.menu["item"+num].gotoAndPlay("s1");
    }
}
```